# How to highlight one point in a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization, scatter-plot

Suppose, I have the following two lists that correspond to x- and y-coordinates.

```py
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I want the first pair `(1,3)` to be in a different color or shape.

How can this be done using python?

Comment: Do you want to change the color and shape of the first pair *in a scatterplot*?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One of the simplest possible answers.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [3,4,5,6,7,8]

plt.plot(x[1:], y[1:], 'ro')
plt.plot(x[0], y[0], 'g*')

plt.show()
```

Comment: It means green asterisk -- like this * but green.

Answer (score 1):

More flexibility is offered with `scatter()` call where you can change marker style, size and color more intuitively (e.g. `D` for diamond).

```py
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [3,4,5,6,7,8]

plt.scatter(x[1:], y[1:], c='blue')
plt.scatter(x[0], y[0], c='red', marker='D', s=100);
```

[image: img]

```py
# you can even write text as a marker
plt.scatter(x[0], y[0], c='red', marker=r'$\tau$', s=100);
```

---

If the point to highlight is not the first point, then a filtering mask might be useful. For example, the following code highlights the third point.

```py
plt.scatter(*zip(*(xy for i, xy in enumerate(zip(x, y)) if i!=2)), marker=6)
plt.scatter(x[2], y[2], c='red', marker=7, s=200);
```

Perhaps, the filtering is simpler with numpy.

```py
data = np.array([x, y])                                # construct a single 2d array
plt.scatter(*data[:, np.arange(len(x))!=2], marker=6)  # plot all except the third point
plt.scatter(*data[:, 2], c='red', marker=7, s=200);    # plot the third point
```

[image: img2]

As a side note, you can find the full dictionary of marker styles [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html) or by `matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle.markers`.

```py
# a dictionary of marker styles
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle
MarkerStyle.markers
```