# highlight one point when extracting data from a text file to graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am able to make graph an X Y graph when extracting data from a text file, but I just need help highlighting one point on the function.

I have this list of data where the first column is the y values and the second is the x values. I would like to just highlight the value (0.718, 1.42676) when plotting this data from a text file.

```
1.3822;0.2
1.43985;0.3
1.45821;0.4
1.45764;0.5
1.4469;0.6
1.43022;0.7
1.42676;0.718
1.4101;0.8
1.38796;0.9
1.3647;1.0

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_file = open('new3b.txt','r')
lines = data_file.readlines()
data_file.close()
kinf_list = []
den_list = []
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] = lines[i].strip('\n')
    line_list = lines[i].split(';')
    kinf_list.append(float(line_list[0]))
    den_list.append(float(line_list[1]))

X = den_list
Y = kinf_list

plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.xlabel('Density (g/cc)')
plt.ylabel('K-INF')
plt.title('Multiplication factor as a function of Density')
plt.plot(X[1:], Y[1:], 'ro')
plt.plot(X[0], Y[0], 'g*')
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('kinfVdenB2.png')
plt.show()
```

The code above works perfect, the only problem is that it does not highlight the desired point on the function.

Comment: The other answer is more generalize-able as it isn't dependent on the order of the data points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you used the method from this answer: [using Matplotlib how to highlight one point in the final plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489543/using-matplotlib-how-to-highlight-one-point-in-the-final-plot). In this case you can just break things up in a similar manner:

```
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.xlabel('Density (g/cc)')
plt.ylabel('K-INF')
plt.title('Multiplication factor as a function of Density')
plt.plot(X[0:6], Y[0:6], 'ro')
plt.plot(X[6], Y[6], 'g*')
plt.plot(X[7:], Y[7:], 'ro')
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('kinfVdenB2.png')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not highlighting the right point because you're giving it the wrong positions in:

```
plt.plot(X[1:], Y[1:], 'ro')
plt.plot(X[0], Y[0], 'g*')
```

A more foolproof way is to do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data_file = open('new3b.txt','r')
lines = data_file.readlines()
data_file.close()
kinf_list = []
den_list = []
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] = lines[i].strip('\n')
    line_list = lines[i].split(';')
    kinf_list.append(float(line_list[0]))
    den_list.append(float(line_list[1]))

X = np.array(den_list)
Y = np.array(kinf_list)

plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.xlabel('Density (g/cc)')
plt.ylabel('K-INF')
plt.title('Multiplication factor as a function of Density')

HighlitghtX,HighlitghtY = 0.718, 1.42676
NotX = X[np.where(X != HighlitghtX)]
NotY = Y[np.where(Y != HighlitghtY)]
YesX = X[np.where(X == HighlitghtX)]
YesY = Y[np.where(Y == HighlitghtY)]

plt.scatter(NotX, NotY, color='r',marker='o',s=50)
plt.scatter(YesX, YesY, color='g',marker='*',s=50)
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('kinfVdenB2.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to highlight multiple, you could do this:

```
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.xlabel('Density (g/cc)')
plt.ylabel('K-INF')
plt.title('Multiplication factor as a function of Density')


HighlitghtX,HighlitghtY = np.array([0.718,0.8]), np.array([1.42676,1.4101])
NotX = X[np.isin(X,HighlitghtX)]
NotY = Y[np.isin(Y,HighlitghtY)]
YesX = X[np.invert(np.isin(X,HighlitghtX))]
YesY = Y[np.invert(np.isin(Y,HighlitghtY))]

print(NotX,YesX)

plt.scatter(NotX, NotY, color='r',marker='o',s=50)
plt.scatter(YesX, YesY, color='g',marker='*',s=50)
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('kinfVdenB2.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]